# Не работает замена подстроки в строке JS

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Существует массив с именами allRoles, а также строковая переменная textSearchIn с текстом. 
Следующий код по идее должен находить в переменной textSearchIn имя из массива, если после него стоит точка, и заменять найденную подстроку в формате "*[имя из массива].", но замены не происходит. В чем может быть проблема?

```js
let textSearchIn = "Городничий. Я пригласил вас, господа, с тем чтобы сообщить вам пренеприятное известие: к нам едет ревизор. Аммос Федорович. Как ревизор? Артемий Филиппович. Как ревизор? Городничий. Ревизор из Петербурга, инкогнито. И еще с секретным предписаньем. Аммос Федорович. Вот те на!";

let allRoles = ["Городничий", "Аммос Федорович", "Артемий Филиппович", "Лука Лукич", "Коробкин", "Жена Коробкина", "Люлюков", "Гостья"];    

let newText;

for (let i = 0; i<allRoles.length; i++) {
    token = allRoles[i]+"\.";
    newText = textSearchIn.replace(new RegExp(token, 'g'), '*'+token);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let textSearchIn = "Городничий. Я пригласил вас, господа, с тем чтобы сообщить вам пренеприятное известие: к нам едет ревизор. Аммос Федорович. Как ревизор? Артемий Филиппович. Как ревизор? Городничий. Ревизор из Петербурга, инкогнито. И еще с секретным предписаньем. Аммос Федорович. Вот те на!";
let allRoles = ["Городничий", "Аммос Федорович", "Артемий Филиппович", "Лука Лукич", "Коробкин", "Жена Коробкина", "Люлюков", "Гостья"];

const reg = new RegExp(`(` + allRoles.join(`\\.)|(`) + `\\.)`, 'gi')
console.log(textSearchIn.replace(reg, (a) => '*' + a))
```

**UPD** Упрощенный вариант без группировки `(...)` от [yar85](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/288409/yar85)

```js
let textSearchIn = "Городничий. Я пригласил вас, господа, с тем чтобы сообщить вам пренеприятное известие: к нам едет ревизор. Аммос Федорович. Как ревизор? Артемий Филиппович. Как ревизор? Городничий. Ревизор из Петербурга, инкогнито. И еще с секретным предписаньем. Аммос Федорович. Вот те на!";
let allRoles = ["Городничий", "Аммос Федорович", "Артемий Филиппович", "Лука Лукич", "Коробкин", "Жена Коробкина", "Люлюков", "Гостья"];

const reg = new RegExp(allRoles.join(`\\.|`), 'gi')
console.log(textSearchIn.replace(reg, '*$&'))
```

Comment: Или, просто `textSearchIn.replace(new RegExp(``(${allRoles.join('\\.|') + '\\.'})``, 'gi'), '*$&')` - только вместо двойных бэктиков одинарные (кажется, сломали разметку комментов, раньше вроде работало такое экранирование).

Comment: @yar85 ..точно!

Answer (score 1):

```js
let textSearchIn = "Городничий. Я пригласил вас, господа, с тем чтобы сообщить вам пренеприятное известие: к нам едет ревизор. Аммос Федорович. Как ревизор? Артемий Филиппович. Как ревизор? Городничий. Ревизор из Петербурга, инкогнито. И еще с секретным предписаньем. Аммос Федорович. Вот те на!";
let allRoles = ["Городничий", "Аммос Федорович", "Артемий Филиппович", "Лука Лукич", "Коробкин", "Жена Коробкина", "Люлюков", "Гостья"];    

let newText = textSearchIn;
for (let i = 0; i < allRoles.length; i++) {
    let token = allRoles[i] + "\.";
    newText = newText.replace(new RegExp(token, 'g'), '*' + token);
}

console.log(newText);
```